# why are not getting data in sdr it from database?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, architecture

### ## In this code why are not getting data in sdr it from database? ##

**below code is business layer class :**

```
public string[] AutoComplete(string Address)
{
   DtAccess objDataAccess = new DtAccess();
   List<string> request = new List<string>();

   SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
   param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Mode", "AutoComplete");
   param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Address", Address);
   using (SqlDataReader sdr = objDataAccess.ExecuteReader(_spName, param))
   {
     while (sdr.Read())
     {
       request.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", sdr["Address"], sdr["Latitute"], sdr["Longitute"]));
      }
   }
   return request.ToArray();
}
```

**And below code is example.aspx.cs page :**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string[] GetAutoCompleteData(string Address)
    {
        BussinessLgc objBussinessLogic = new BussinessLgc();
        return objBussinessLogic.AutoComplete(Address);            
    }
```

**[UPDATE]**

**Ajax Code is following:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toAddress").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Root.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData") %>',
                data: "{ 'Address': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d.length == 0) {
                        $('.ui-autocomplete').hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".pac-container").hide();
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1],
                                long: item.split('-')[2]
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=DestinationSLat.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
            $("#<%=DestinationELng.ClientID %>").val(i.item.long);
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

I try above `jQuery` for getting data from `GetAutoCompleteData` WebMethod. But data not come in srd from Database..

Comment: Post Your `Ajax Jquery` which runs the above webservice

Comment: Have you tried executing same in SQL server console and put a try catch see if there is exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your path of the aspx/Webmethod from

```
url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Root.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData") %>'
```

to

```
 url: '<%=ResolveUrl("Root.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData") %>' //with out ~/
```

also put `TRY...CATCH` in your `Business layer` Function as @Arindam Nayak said

Comment: Check the path of Root.Aspx and also Put a breakpoint in your JQuery and check it

Comment: path of Root.aspx is perfect. and i check using breakpoint then data.d.length always 0 .

Comment: 0 means your are not getting any data based on the value you have entered try to run your SP in SSMS with same data